is there a way to use generic types in graaljs?
it seems that in graaljs you cannot simply go Java.type("Foo<Bar>")
using Java.type("com.mojang.brigadier.Command<com.mojang.brigadier.ServerCommandSource>"), it says that that class does not exist (for reference this is running on a fabric 1.21 server, during the onInitalise call). this has led me to search code for how to do this.

generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination. It's entirely a compile time affair. javac knows what they are and applies the logic. java.exe has very little (the vast majority disappear - they never make it to the .class file), and the rest is, literally, a comment as far as java.exe is concerned: It has no idea what it means. Hence, this, which at runtime tries to create a type, is fundamentally impossible. The answer to your question is: No - it doesn't even make sense; that is not what generics are and not how they work.

I'm not familiar with graal, so this might be missing some details. It may be wise to edit your question and include what you're trying to do; this sounds like an X/Y problem (you have unstated problem X, and thought: I know! I'll call Java.type("Foo<Bar>")! oh, wait, that does not work, let me ask a question about this) - you need to ask about X instead.

@rzwitserloot: although someone coming from other programming languages which have more robust generics might not realize that with Java, generics are really second class citizens. Although, yes, you are spot on, as always.

@HovercraftFullOfEels Java's generics is very robust. It's just not reified. Reified generics (such as C templates) has a ton of downside. It also has a ton of upside. It's.. different. "More robust" is not the right terminology here. It's not a second class citizen either. I can't find it now, but I believe it was Brian Goetz who wrote a defense of non-reified generics that highlights the many, many benefits of this choice. And it's not ".. was backwards compatible with java 1.4". No, benefits as in: "This was the right choice even if part of java 1.0".

@rzwitserloot: again, I can't argue your points as your depth of knowledge in this subject is greater than mine, but I was thinking of how generics compare in Java vs C#. Since in C# generics does not type erase the the generic type on compilation, they exist fully in the runtime code. This would allow something akin to what the OP is trying to do and would allow identification of generic type on reflection. C# also has primitive type support, which allows simplification of the code base, such as for functional interfaces.

The main down-side that I can see, and that you mentioned is that such changes would have made for breaking changes in the newer language version that allowed for this, as which happened when C# went from version 1.0 to 2.0. This would be a bigger deal for Java than for C# at that time, I believe, since Java's penetrance was much much greater, and so a lot of code base, much of it running key large business applications, would be at risk of breaking.

@HovercraftFullOfEels If we're just thinking of List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();, java's choice is hard to explain as somehow better or at least 'different but not worse'. However, start considering List<Map<? extends List<? super Number>, V> and 'runtime introspectable generics' starts looking like a nasty mess. Which it is.
